# how to separate the parameters in the sql query and push it in to array to avoid sql injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE year_month BETWEEN '2021-08' AND '2022-01';

update table2 set note_description = 'test @8:57am', patient_id = '5840', note_updated_by = '10000019', note_update_date = '2022-07-13 09:45:49' where note_id = '639'
```

now my backend queries can be attacked by sql injection so i want to avoid the sql injection
in the above queries I want to separate the parameters from queries and replace it with special characters so that I can avoid sql injection is there any package or anything to do it.

Comment: You would use Prepared Statements/Parameterized Queries to avoid SQL injection when dealing with user input.  How you do this depends on the language/environment your using to execute your SQL which you have not specified.

Comment: What kind of application do you use? That's where SQL injection starts and that's where you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have received the SQL statement with the parameters already concatenated in, then this is the wrong place to fix your issue - there’s no way to safely parse the statement and separate out the parameters from the query.

You should find the place in the code where  the parameters are concatenated into the  Statement and leveraging Prepared Statements/Parameterized Queries to safely pass/bind the parameters.

If that’s not possible (for example because  the code is structured to only pass along the statement) a less desirable alternative is to encode/enquote the parameters before concatenating them in, while ensuring they are all quoted in the statement.  How you do that part will depend on the database / language being used.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen one product that does this: [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html). It's a free tool that parses the MySQL query log, and produces reports of aggregate time spent running each query. To do this, it must establish a query "fingerprint" which allows it to group queries that are the same except for constant values. Like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 123` has the same fingerprint as `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 456`.

This means it must parse the queries and replace each constant value, like a numeric or string literal, with a placeholder `?`. In cases of `IN()` predicates, it replaces the list of values with `?+`. Also it reduces whitespace and removes comments.

It's a non-trivial amount of code, about 100 lines of Perl: https://github.com/percona/percona-toolkit/blob/3.x/lib/QueryRewriter.pm#L139-L248
In spite of this, the function is preceded by a comment that the developers acknowledge it is not perfect, and may miss some cases. Implementing a recursive-descent parser using regular expressions is not efficient or correct.

But this is probably not what you want to do anyway. You shouldn't be starting from a query with constant values and making them into a parameterized query. You should design parameterized queries yourself, as needed.

Not every constant value in an SQL query necessarily must be parameterized. Only the ones that aren't fixed values. That is, if you need to combine a variable from your client code into the SQL query string, and you can't guarantee that the variable is safe, then use a parameter. If a query has a constant value that is fixed (not interpolated from a variable), then it can remain in the query. If a query has a value that comes from a variable, but that variable is known to be safe, and never can be tainted by untrusted input, then it can remain in the query.

It's more reliable and economical for you to make these judgments. You know the code and the context much better than any automated system can.